# Predicates java 8 with generics and inheritance

Tags: java, generics, java-8, predicate

I'm having three Foo Boo Goo objects with Boo and Goo subtypes of Foo super class.

I'm using Predicates to filter lists as following

```
public class Predicates {

        public static Predicate<Foo> isBoo() {
            foo ->  { 
                  Boo boo = (Boo) foo; 
                  return boo.isBoo();
             };
         }

    public static Predicate<Goo> isGoo() {
            foo ->  { 
                  Goo goo = (Goo) foo; 
                  return goo.isGoo();
             };
     }
}
```

What i want to acheive next is to have a generic type instead of compile-time types specified.

```
public class Predicates {

        public static <T extends Foo> Predicate<T> isBoo() {
            foo ->  { 
                  // check both with instanceof
             };
         }

    public static <T extends Foo> Predicate<T> isGoo() {
            foo ->  { 
                  Goo goo = (Goo) foo; 
                  return boo.isGoo();
             };
     }

    public static <T extends Foo> Predicate<T> isFoo() {
            isGoo().or(isBoo());
     }
}
```

It seems impossible to use generics with Predicates when having anoter one combining multiples predicates with OR or AND. Knowing the predicates may have differents types buts still extends the super class.

Need light!

Comment: Why not simply `public static Predicate<? super Foo> isBoo() {`?

Comment: I don't know why but at compilation. i cannot have two different types in a same list even if those inherit from the same super class!

Comment: I'm not sure why you  are trying to accomplish using wildcard for the value type that the predicate may accept. That type-param is an statement of what kind of object the predicate can handle and not  what kind of object the predicate would return true for. I think you are confusing both things here. Given the example above you could use ```Predicate<Object>``` anywhere as an "instanceof" is applicable to any object.

Comment: For example, would ever isBoo() return false if (Boo) cast worked? Same for Goo. I think you should try to make the code example a bit less trivial and more realistic showing that what you intent may have some actual use.

Comment: Perhaps you should add some code where that predicate is going to be use to achieve something practical.

Comment: @ValentinRuano up

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you define multiple predicates for each subtype, add these predicates to a list, and finally constructs a predicate by doing an `or` of all the predicates in the list.

```java
public static Predicate<Foo> anotherIsFoo() {
    return predicates.stream()
            .reduce(foo -> false, (a, b) -> a.or(b));
}
```

The above code assumes that `predicates` is the list which contains all the predicates for each subtype.

The complete code looks like this:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Foo {}
class Boo extends Foo {}
class Goo extends Foo {}

public class Predicates {
    public static List<Predicate<Foo>> predicates = List.of(isGoo(), isFoo());

    public static Predicate<Foo> isGoo() {
        return foo -> foo instanceof Goo;
    }

    public static Predicate<Foo> isBoo() {
        return goo -> goo instanceof Boo;
    }

    public static Predicate<Foo> anotherIsFoo() {
        return predicates.stream()
            .reduce(foo -> false, (a, b) -> a.or(b));
    }

    public static Predicate<Foo> isFoo() {
        return foo -> foo instanceof Foo;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Foo> list = List.of(new Boo(), new Goo(), new Goo(), new Goo());
        List<Boo> boos = list.stream()
                .filter(Predicates.isBoo())
                .map(boo -> (Boo) boo)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(boos.size()); // 1

        List<Goo> goos = list.stream()
                .filter(Predicates.isGoo())
                .map(goo -> (Goo) goo)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(goos.size()); //3

        List<Foo> foos = list.stream()
                .filter(Predicates.isFoo())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(foos.size()); // 4

        List<Foo> foos1 = list.stream()
                .filter(Predicates.anotherIsFoo())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(foos1.size()); // 4
    }
}
```

The above code answers your query - "I cannot have two different types in a same list even if those inherit from the same super class!"

The above code requires Java 9 or higher.

Comment: I really like your proposition. But i have properties in my subclasses that i want to access in the predicate to apply the test(). When only checking the instance of a object of superclass type, this requirement is not acheived and i don't have access to child properties